# Critical Updates "Auto-Activation Date"

Tags: administration, update, developer, critical-update

https://help.salesforce.com/htcasesuggestedsolutions?filterid=&id=5003000000Xo4rpAAB

Salesforce's own documentation states that the Auto-Activation date of Critical Updates is the date they force the update on you, you cannot turn it of, etc etc.

Anyone know the reality of this?

In 4 years, I've yet to see any consistency on this.  I have two past-due updates they're not forcing on me yet.

**Example**:

- Serve Static Resources from the Visualforce Domain
- Auto-Activation:  12/10/2014 - 0 days remaining

**Example**:

- Enable governor limits on all executed flows
- Auto-Activation:  1/11/2015 - 0 days remaining

Thanks!

**Update** 2015-02-03 from SF Support:       I heard back from some of my colleagues on other skill group teams. With regards to the Enable Governor Limits, we are going to create a separate case with our Config team to take this up with Tier 3 / R&D to investigate see if they can determine why this particular critical update did not take place as scheduled. They may also have more for you in terms of messaging as to why they remain in the list and the due date does not update.  (**my translation - left hand, right hand, no clue right now**)  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the issue was finally uncovered that SF was arbitrarily delaying updates or otherwise altering the actual deployment date.  So even though day-zero comes and goes, they may not apply.  It's been almost 2 years since this, so the behavior may be more consistent now.  (?)

Answer (score 3):

Different servers run different versions of salesforce at any given time. It's rare to see all servers on the exact same version, even mid-release.

The auto activation date is, as far as I can tell, based in the scheduled release for a patch or release. Sometimes, like all things software, something fails QA, or a patch has to roll back because it broke a server, or the patch is delayed because developers fell behind.

Whatever the case, you should always assume that the patch will go out on the day specified, so you're not caught off guard. Just know that, like any other company, patches don't always go as planned, so there is always a possibility you might have a little extra time than specified.

Comment: I agree with everything you said.  The shortcoming is (as is frequently the case I find) on Salesforce's end.   If they are NOT going to enforce an auto-activation date, they should warn us, put a marker on the critical update itself, remove it as a critical update, etc etc etc... something including some of what I just wrote.   They are not (clearly) as I just finally received a reply that ONE of the two (most recent) updates I posted on this article are NOT GOING TO BE PUSHED until the NEXST RELEASE now.  But we sit there and see these "IT WILL DEPLOY, BE WARNED" popups, continuously.  :-P