# Restrict Access to @AuraEnabled Apex Methods for Authenticated Users Based on User Profile

Tags: community, security, update, security-review, critical-update

This update is getting enforce in my org on the 5th of April 202o, since some of the updates in my org are having deactivation options after enforcement and some of them are not having. so  I want to know that will this update have a deactivation option after the 5th of April when it will automatically activate in my org?

Answer (score 2):

You must read this:-

[Notes on Critical Updates](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cruc_overview.htm&type=5)

1. Salesforce analyzes your organization to determine if a critical
   update potentially affects your customizations. If your
   customizations aren’t affected, Salesforce automatically activates
   the update in your organization.
2. On the scheduled auto-activation date, **Salesforce permanently
   activates the update**. After auto-activation, you can’t deactivate
   the update.
3. Each update detail page describes how your customizations might be
   affected and how you can correct any unintended behavior.
4. Salesforce displays a message the first time you access Setup after
   a critical update becomes available. The message lets you choose to
   have Salesforce display the updates immediately or remind you about
   the updates later.

### Update

Also, You might be interested to read this:- [Critical Updates “Auto-Activation Date”](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64693/critical-updates-auto-activation-date)

Comment: but some of the critical updates are having deactivation option even  after the auto-activation  date likewise will this critical update have a deactivation option?